# Creating new sheet using Apache POI removes all the existing sheets

Tags: java, apache-poi

I trying to add new sheet to an existing excel file using Apache poi library as in the below code.

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(BASE_PATH+outputFile));

            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Splitted Rules");

            Set<String> tags = outputRules.keySet();
            int i = 0;
            for (String tag : tags) {
                List<String> rules = outputRules.get(tag);
                for (String rule : rules) {
                    Row row = sheet.createRow(i++);
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(tag);
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rule);
                }
            }

            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            wb.close();`
```

The problem is that all the sheets in the file is deleted and only the new sheets exist.

What is this problem ?

Comment: What do you know about how files work?

Comment: Thanks @immibis your comment guided me. I should initiate the FileOutputStream in append mode.

Comment: That also won't work, for the same reason you can't just concatenate two Excel files and get one with their combined sheets. You need to load the workbook, add your sheet, save the workbook - same as you'd do manually in Excel (or whichever program it is, if it's not Excel).

Comment: i'm guessing that `fileOut` is an instance of FilteOutputStream. How exactly are you initializing that ?

Comment: FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(BASE_PATH+outputFile));

Comment: As explained [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewSheet), I think you don't have to pass a `new File` instance, just the absolute path of sheet will do, something like `FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream( BASE_PATH+outputFile );`

Comment: You don't appear to be loading in the existing file before making changes to it! What happens if you try adding some code to the start to load the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments already hint at the solution.

The code above creates a new workbook and overwrites any existing file.

If you want to append a sheet to an existing workbook use the WorkbookFactory.create method (or the XSSFWorkbook constructors with the appropriate argument) to create the workbook based on the existing excel file.